# How to apply custom css class to extjs grid column, and remove it with delay?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4

The goal is to apply one `cls` to column, which I did with  `getRowClass` and then remove it after 1-2 sec. The *websync* is pushing new data every 5 seconds, so when this changes to cell appear, it should be like a blink of a changed column(cell), that goes back to "white"(default) before new data refresh? The value assigned to compare new records with is 0, but in a real case is *last value* that is being compared! 
Here is my code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    columns: [
    // ...
    {
        header: 'Change',
        dataIndex: 'change',
        tdCls: 'x-change-cell'
    }
    // ...
    ],

    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, index) {
            var c = record.get('change');
            if (c < 0) {
                return 'price-fall';
                //   I tried setTimeout("remove-css()",1000); and
                //    Ext.Function.defer(remove-css, 1000);
                //     but no luck!!
            } else if (c > 0) {
                return 'price-rise';
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```

**CSS:**

```css
.price-fall .x-change-cell {
    background-color: #FFB0C4;
    color:red;
}
.price-rise .x-change-cell {
    background-color: #B0FFC5;
    color:green;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
store.on('add', function() {
    var els = Ext.select('.price-fall', this.getEl());
    els.each(function(el) {
        el.removeCls('price-fall');
    });
    els = Ext.select('.price-rise', this.getEl());
    els.each(function(el) {
        el.removeCls('price-rise');
    });
}, grid, { delay: 2000 });
```

Here the add event is fired with 2sek delay.

And I've found another solution:

```
getRowClass: function(rec, index) {
    if (rec.get('rendered') === undefined) {
        Ext.Function.defer(function() {
            this.removeRowCls(index, 'price-fall');
            this.removeRowCls(index, 'price-rise');
            rec.set('rendered', true); // mark row, in case there repaint occur
        }, 2000, this);

        if (rec.get('change') < 0) {
            return 'price-fall';
        } else {
            return 'price-rise';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do delay part, can you implement this line to code? If i do delay after return i get no result??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'If i do delay after return i get no result??'. No code after return statement is invoked.
You can invoke it with delay like this for example: `(function(grid){ Ext.select('.price-rise', grid.getEl()).each(function(el){ el.removeClass('price-rise'); }); }.defer(2000, this, [ grid ]));`. This code should be invoked in some event handler (you can bind it to Ext.data.Store.add event).

Comment: @Lolo- In the second solution, what does rec.get('rendered') represents?

Comment: @Ingol - it's a marker; without it sometimes old rows were rendered with price-rise/price-drop class (for example after sorting grid). I suppose that is not wanted behaviour. But this is only example, and you should customize it to fit your needs.

Comment: @Lolo- I did it, but it only goes for first value render, the second and the rest just shows values , no custom css or remving the same? Any ideas here?

Comment: @Ingol - Not sure what are you asking about. But there may be an issue when you insert row in the middle, then indexes can change within 2 seconds. It's better to call `this.removeRowCls(rec, 'price-fall');` instead of `this.removeRowCls(index, 'price-fall');`.

Comment: @Lolo- Thanks, that's it! Works like a charm! Now to add effect ;-)